# Why do syn scans not work over proxy set up through SSH's dynamic port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, nmap

I have set up dynamic port forwarding using SSH. Although nmap scans over proxychains return accurate results, a SYN scan does not.

Comment: What kind of inaccurate results? Have you run a packet capture to see what's going on?

Comment: everything shows up as filtered. I have not set up a packet scan. will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH port forwarding and also proxychains forward the **payload** of TCP **connections** and not the original raw IP packets. A SYN scan does not create a TCP connection and does not have any application payload so it will not not work with port forwarding or other TCP proxies.

Comment: can you link me to some docs regarding this

Comment: @Swagger68: No explicit docs about this specific topic of SYN scans vs. proxies. This conclusion comes from an understanding of what SYN scans are and how proxies and SSH port forwarding works, So you need to learn how TCP works, what a TCP connection is, what a SYN scan is, how proxies work etc - off-topic.

Comment: okay I have read and understood TCP part. Im not able to find any good reading on port forwarding/ proxies at the packet level. Please link me to them if you can.

Comment: If only payload is sent, does that mean the proxy IP takes care of the TCP connection part [SYN, ACK, SYN ACK]? That would make sense and explain why SYN packets do not get forwarded.

Comment: @Swagger68: Yes, that's exactly how proxies work. They terminate the connection from the client and create a new connection to the server, then transfer the payload between client and server.